# compress my asp pages with gzip

Tags: asp-classic, gzip

trying to compress my asp pages, done this but nothing, what can i do?

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

Comment: is that a web.config fil? that has nothing to do with classic asp...

Comment: have a look here: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: dont understand this :s

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Enable compression as described on microsoft web site. See link from 12/Dec/2013.

[image]

Step 2: Make sure that direct metabase edit is enabled.

Step 3: Stop all IIS related services, and make changes in file \system32\inetsrv\metabase.xml:

```
<IIsCompressionScheme      Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate"
              HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
              HcCreateFlags="0"
              HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
              HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
              HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
              HcDynamicCompressionLevel="10"
              HcFileExtensions="css
                     txt
                     gif
                     png
                     js
                     htm
                     html"
              HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
              HcPriority="1"
              HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
                     dll
                     exe"
       >
</IIsCompressionScheme>
<IIsCompressionScheme      Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/gzip"
              HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
              HcCreateFlags="1"
              HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
              HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
              HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
              HcDynamicCompressionLevel="10"
              HcFileExtensions="css
                     txt
                     gif
                     png
                     js
                     htm
                     html"
              HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
              HcPriority="1"
              HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
                     dll
                     exe"
       >
</IIsCompressionScheme>
```